# How to force a DTO class to be in Swagger models

Tags: java, spring, swagger, dto

I have a SpringBoot application with Swagger 3.17.1.

I have one abstract class `AbstractDtoClass` and one DTO class `DtoClass` that extends the first one.

I have several REST request definitions, and all returns a `AbstractDtoClass` object, none returns `DtoClass`.

As a result, the Swagger models, i.e. the DTO models I can find in "definitions" from /v2/api-docs, contains `AbstractDtoClass` but not `DtoClass`.

I would like `DtoClass` to be in the Swagger models too. How can I do that?

I have tried to put `@SwaggerDefinition` on the `DtoClass` definition.
I have tried to put `@ApiModel(parent = AbstractDtoClass.class)` on the `DtoClass` definition.
I have tried to put `@ApiModel(subTypes = {DeclarationDto.class}, discriminator = "DeclarationDto")` on the `AbstractDtoClass` definition even though I am not sure I am using discriminator properly.

Nothing have worked.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of following method to add additional models that are not part of any annotation or are perhaps implicit.

`springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket#additionalModels(ResolvedType first, ResolvedType... remaining)`

Below is the sample DocketConfig,

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

private final TypeResolver typeResolver;


public SwaggerConfig(final TypeResolver typeResolver) {
    this.typeResolver = typeResolver;
}

@Bean
public Docket docketApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.rmurugaian.service.pricing.server"))
        .build()
        .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(DummyDTO.class));
}
```